# How to find the probability of one score over other if they follow a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I am predicting scores over a golf tournament, what I want is to find the probability of one player bets another player on the same tournament. For example, the predicted score of player A is 63, while the predicted score of player B is 65, how can I convert this into probabilities that let me decide how likely is that player A win over player B? I know from the distribution of predicted and actual scores that the scores follow either a normal or Poisson distribution.

Comment: You probably want the Poisson distribution, as golf scores can only take integer values (it's impossible for player A to beat player B with a final score of 62.3 to 62.7, for example). You also only need a single parameter to define the distribution (the mean), as opposed to a normal distribution which requires two (mean and variance).

Comment: Yes! That's true. How can get that probability using a Poisson distribution? If the mean score of the event is 66 and player A has a predicted score of 63 and player B has a predicted score of 65, how can I get the probability of player A wins over player B?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "predicted score" for each player. It would be reasonable to model each player as having their own Poisson distribution of possible scores, with player A having Poisson-distributed scores with a mean of 63, and B having Poisson-distributed scores with a mean of 65. As long as you know the characteristics of how each player performs, you won't need to know anything about how other players perform (the mean score of the event as a whole).

Comment: I am using a linear model to get the predicted scores of each player base on the characteristics in previous tournaments. Player A has a predicted base on the linear model of 63 and player B has a predicted value of 65.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal RVs with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$, then $X_1-X_2$ is normal with mean $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ and variance $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$, so
$$P(X_1 < X_2) = P(X_1-X_2 < 0) = P\left(\frac{X_1-X_2 - (\mu_1 - \mu_2)}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}} < - \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}} \right) = \Phi\left(- \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}} \right).$$

The missing pieces of information you need are the variances of the two players' predicted scores, and the assertion that their scores are independent. If they are not independent but you know the correlation $\rho$ of their scores, then the variance of $X_1-X_2$ will $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 - 2 \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2$ instead.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have two players that are in the same tournament I assume that I need to use the same mean for both players? The mean of the predicted scores is 73, and the variance of the predicted scores is 1.17. I also have the mean of the actual scores, but I don'T understand what should be X1 and X2 and µ1 and µ2. Can you please help me to understand?

Comment: @PastorSoto I was under the assumption that the predicted scores $63$ and $65$ would be your two means.